# mysql procedure does not return the right value

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, select

whem i do this select:

```
SELECT COUNT(prd_cod) 
FROM product
WHERE prd_name = 'car';
```

it's return 2

and whem i do this procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selection`(IN text VARCHAR(100),OUT 
res   VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(prd_cod) INTO res
FROM product
WHERE prd_name = text;
END;

call selection('car',@res);
```

gives no error, but also returns nothing

someone knows what's going on ?

tanks...

Comment: I know I don't need to put the result as output parameter, but I'm doing a study, and I can't walk from here ...

Comment: i would like to know how do i call it in php too ... tanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing just 1 final step: selecting @res :) The procedure call you make is simply placing the count into the `@res` variable. In order to display it, do `select @res` after the `call`!